Flowable End Event Execution Listener Fails After Boundary Timer Event Trigger
I'm encountering an issue while using the Flowable workflow engine. I have a simple process definition that includes a start event, a user task, and an end event. To monitor the state changes of the process, I've added listeners to these events:
Start event has an ExecutionListener.
User task has a TaskListener.
End event has an ExecutionListener.
When the process runs normally (with the asynchronous executor disabled), all listeners trigger correctly. However, when I add a boundary timer event to the user task to simulate delayed processing and set the timer expiration to jump to the end event, the execution listener on the end event throws an exception, indicating that it cannot find the corresponding class.
Environment Configuration:
Flowable Version: [6.7.2]
Java Version: [Java 11]
Asynchronous Executor Configuration: Disabled
Flowable flowchart
Exception
<process id="estimate" name="工时评估" isExecutable="true">
<documentation>评估工时</documentation>
<startEvent id="startEvent1" flowable:formFieldValidation="true">
<extensionElements>
<flowable:formProperty id="taskName" name="任务信息" type="string" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="taskId" name="id" type="string" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="estimateGroupName" name="任务所属小组" type="string" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="estimateEndDate" name="估算截止日期" type="date" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="estimateGroupId" name="任务所属小组ID" type="hide" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="companyId" name="集团id" type="hide" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:executionListener event="start" expression="${beforeEstimateListener.notify(execution)}"/>
</extensionElements>
</startEvent>
<userTask id="sid-0A081AFA-F761-4A65-A607-7BB05C8894F0" name="评估" flowable:assignee="${userId}" flowable:formFieldValidation="true">
<extensionElements>
<flowable:formProperty id="taskName" name="任务信息" type="string" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="taskId" name="id" type="string" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="estimateGroupName" name="任务所属小组" type="string" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="estimateWork" name="预估工作量" type="double" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="estimateTime" name="估算时间" type="date" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="remark" name="备注说明" type="text"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="estimateGroupId" name="任务所属小组ID" type="hide" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="companyId" name="集团id" type="hide" writable="false" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="estimateMinWork" name="预估[最小]工时" type="string" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="estimateOptWork" name="预估[最大]工时" type="string" required="true"/>
<flowable:formProperty id="formulaType" name="计算公式类型" type="long" required="true"/>
<flowable:taskListener event="complete" class="com.jshxhb.module.main.biz.listener.estimate.AfterEstimateListener"/>
<modeler:initiator-can-complete xmlns:modeler="http://flowable.org/modeler">
<![CDATA[ false ]]>
</modeler:initiator-can-complete>
</extensionElements>
<multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false" flowable:collection="${userList}" flowable:elementVariable="userId">
<extensionElements/>
<completionCondition>${nrOfInstances==nrOfCompletedInstances}</completionCondition>
</multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
</userTask>
<endEvent id="sid-6F2A3DF1-5DBB-44E3-BBBC-FAB1402A2059">
<extensionElements>
<flowable:executionListener event="end" expression="${completeEstimateListener.notify(execution)}"/>
</extensionElements>
</endEvent>
<boundaryEvent id="sid-9D12A2E3-A215-42CD-8CD4-EB34915E0B1F" attachedToRef="sid-0A081AFA-F761-4A65-A607-7BB05C8894F0" cancelActivity="true">
<timerEventDefinition>
<timeDate>${estimateEndDateFlowable}</timeDate>
</timerEventDefinition>
</boundaryEvent>
<sequenceFlow id="sid-D605E910-ECB2-4ACF-9189-C34D13028AFA" sourceRef="sid-0A081AFA-F761-4A65-A607-7BB05C8894F0" targetRef="sid-6F2A3DF1-5DBB-44E3-BBBC-FAB1402A2059"/>
<sequenceFlow id="sid-CD131945-5FD4-4F28-BBF2-544DD964DD90" sourceRef="startEvent1" targetRef="sid-0A081AFA-F761-4A65-A607-7BB05C8894F0"/>
<endEvent id="sid-4E25BB52-1242-4745-907C-E5C9C9DB5806">
<extensionElements>
<flowable:executionListener event="end" class="com.jshxhb.module.main.biz.listener.estimate.CompleteEstimateListener"/>
</extensionElements>
</endEvent>
<sequenceFlow id="sid-E947622F-B63B-4307-BEAF-1A7B2F603F5C" sourceRef="sid-9D12A2E3-A215-42CD-8CD4-EB34915E0B1F" targetRef="sid-4E25BB52-1242-4745-907C-E5C9C9DB5806"/>
</process>

I expect the execution listener on the end event to trigger correctly after the timer expires, without throwing any exceptions.
Checked that the listener class path and name are correct.
Ensured the class is in the right package path and can be picked up by Flowable.
Disabled the asynchronous executor to rule out asynchronous execution issues.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue?
Do you have any suggestions for debugging this kind of problem?
Are there specific configuration or implementation details to look out for?
